# I am confused with javascript let and var in for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, scope, var, let

Here is my code for loop

```
var username = ['Sam', 'Adarsh', 'Rohit', 'Rajat'];
for(var i in username){
  console.log(username[i]);
}
```

it's outputing the same as needed, But I am not sure why Let declaration needed. I understand the concept of VAR and LET but not sure in which cases var create problem in for loops ?

Any body please help me to understant the concept. I am new noob and trying to figure out :)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The problem with that code isn't with `var`, it's with the fact that you're using a `for..in` loop to iterate over an array, [which is a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/5743988).

Comment: I just wanna know let and var role in any for loop ... Can you give me a example ?

Comment: Use neither, and go for `Array.forEach`

Comment: @RajatSharma let create the block scope in for(in) {}, so outside the for(in) {} loop, you can't get the value of i

Comment: But use `for .. in` loop to array is bad usage.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you use `var`:

```
var username = ['Sam', 'Adarsh', 'Rohit', 'Rajat'];
for(var i in username){
  console.log(username[i]);
}
i // 3
```

When you use `let`

```
var username = ['Sam', 'Adarsh', 'Rohit', 'Rajat'];
for(let i in username){
  console.log(username[i]);
}
i // Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined
```

`let` in ES6 will create **block scope to function scope**

Comment: `let` create the block scope in `for(in) {}`, so outside the `for(in) {}` loop, you can't get the value of `i`.

Comment: Actually I am studying about "Problem with var in for loops" ... with closures function ...which is over come by let -- Can you please help me about this topic .. Thanks in advance

Comment: @RajatSharma the main point is **closures** not the `for in`.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1 this answer tell me clearly: what is closure.

Comment: Using `let i in username` has drastic performance issues with respect to `let i = 0; i < username.length; i++`

Comment: No one seems to care but it is bothering me and worth mentioning: for...in should not be used for collections, it is meant only for object property traversal and does not guarantee the traversal order.

Comment: Does anyone have a link where I can investigate further why 'for ... in' should not be used for collections?

Comment: @JesseRezaKhorasanee `for in` always need to be used with `hasOwnProperty`. Your question can see this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in

Comment: the second example actually *doesn't* produce `Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined` - it works fine…

Comment: @DaveEveritt you run second example in browser?

Comment: Yes, I did in a simple html5 page

Comment: @DaveEveritt You can try in nodejs

Comment: @tomioion @DaveEveritt it's funny, the value of `i` on this Stack Overflow page is `undefined` for some reason. So if you are testing in the inspector on this page, you will not get the reference error. Swap `i` out for another variable name (`a`) and you will get the error.